# What is the specific use of wild cards in generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am confused about the use of the wild cards in generics of java.
I know how to use them but I don't understand when I should use them .

I have learnt that wild cards can be used like this

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<? extends Number> list){}
```

but it can be written as this as well
`public static <T extends Number> void sort(ArrayList<T> list){}`

So, what is the actual use and advantage of wild cards?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to firegloves' excellent answer, you should also note, that you definitely need type parameters, when you have the same parameter at multiple places.

Example: we want to apply a consumer to each element of a list, the data type is derived from number:

This does not work:

```
private void consumeList(List<? extends Number> listOfThings, Consumer<? extends Number> consumer) {
    listOfThings.forEach(consumer);
}
```

... because the first "?" is not the same as the second "?".

However, this works fine:

```
private <T extends Number> void consumeListTyped(List<T> listOfThings, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    listOfThings.forEach(consumer);
}
```

... because you define **a single "T"**, which you use multiple times.

Comment: "This does not work:" of course, it would work if you used `? super Number` for the Consumer:

Answer (score 0):

The use of wildcards (`?`) and type parameters (`<T>`) in Java generics both serve to introduce type safety and flexibility in your code, but they cater to slightly different scenarios. Understanding when to use each can help you write more versatile and robust code. Here's a breakdown of their uses and advantages:

**Wildcards** are used to specify that a type is unknown. The `?` symbol represents an unknown type. Wildcards are particularly useful in scenarios where you only need to read from a collection and the exact type of the elements in the collection doesn't impact the operation you're performing. They introduce flexibility by allowing a method to operate on collections of various types as long as they adhere to a certain boundary (upper bound with `? extends Type`, lower bound with `? super Type`).

**Type parameters**, on the other hand, are used to define a method or class with a type that can be specified later. They allow for more generic and reusable code. When you define a method like `public static <T extends Number> void sort(ArrayList<T> list)`, you're specifying that the method is applicable to an `ArrayList` of any single type that is a subtype of `Number`, and you can both read from and write to the list with the safety of knowing exactly what type of objects are supposed to be in that list.

Flexibility with Specificity: With type parameters, you can maintain type safety throughout the operation. Since the exact type `T` is known within the method, you can add elements of type `T` to the list, return objects of type T, and so on. This approach is more type-safe compared to using wildcards, as it ensures that the type used is consistent.

**Choosing Between Wildcards and Type Parameters**

- Use wildcards when: You're designing a method that only reads from a data structure and the operation is generic enough that it applies to a wide range of types.
- Use type parameters when: The method performs operations that depend on the type parameter, such as adding or removing elements from a collection, or when you need to enforce a specific type relationship that will be used consistently throughout the method.

In summary, wildcards offer greater flexibility for method parameters when the exact type doesn't matter for the method's implementation. Type parameters offer more specificity and type safety, allowing for a broader range of operations within the method, including adding elements to the collection, which isn't safely possible with wildcards due to their inherent unknown type.

**Example 1: Processing a List of Numbers**

Suppose you have a method that processes a list of numbers and you are only interested in reading the numbers and possibly computing their sum. In such a case, using wildcards would be appropriate.
Using Wildcards

```
public static double sum(List<? extends Number> list) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (Number n : list) {
        sum += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In this example, `List<? extends Number>` allows the sum method to accept a list of any subclass of Number (like `Integer`, `Double`, etc.). The method can read from the list, but you are restricted from adding elements to it because the specific subtype of Number is unknown, which aligns perfectly with the method's purpose of computing a sum without modifying the list.

**Example 2: Adding Elements of a Specific Type to a List**

Now, consider a scenario where you need a method to add a specific type of number to a list. In this case, type parameters would be more suitable as you have more control and can ensure type safety when adding elements to the list.
Using Type Parameters

```
public static <T extends Number> void addToList(List<T> list, T element) {
    list.add(element);
}
```

In this method, `List<T>` along with `<T extends Number>` ensures that both the list and the element to add are of the same specific subtype of Number. This method is type-safe, allowing you to add elements to the list without risking a ClassCastException.

**Conclusion**

Wildcards (`? extends Number`) are best used when you are dealing with a collection from which you intend to read or process elements without modifying the collection. They provide flexibility by allowing your method to accept a collection of any type that extends a certain base type.

Type Parameters (`<T extends Number>`) are preferable when you want to perform operations that modify the collection, need to enforce type consistency, or when the method's logic depends on the type of elements in the collection. They ensure type safety and allow for a broader range of operations within the method.

Answer (score 0):

Another use for type variables over wildcards is to express constraints on the unknown types.

For example:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

is a type which can be compared to itself. You can't express this without the type variables, because you need to refer to the unknown type in more than one place.

However, this is more usefully written with both a type variable *and* a wildcard:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

which allows the type to be subclasses of something that is comparable, e.g. an implementation of an interface which extends Comparable.